# Change the format of an Image in java without saving

Tags: java, png

I would like to read an image and then change its format but without saving it.

For example I can read the image like this
`BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));`

Then I want to change the format of `img`, for example from jpeg to png.
The only way I found is to use `ImageIO.read` to write and then read the new image, but it does seem to be an efficient way to do it.

Comment: You have no other option

Comment: `BufferedImage` is "unformatted" (in respect to the file format, it's a representation of the image data and color model which can be used within Java and it's related classes), so what you're asking actually makes no sense.  `BufferedImage` doesn't now from what format it come from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you "read" the image via

```
BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File('myimage.png'));
```

you are not only reading but also decoding it, i.e., transforming the raw bytes in the (say) PNG format to some "RAW" format that your aplication or API can manipulate (or display) - in this case, a `BufferedImage`. Once this is done, the fact that this image came from a PNG file is forgotten. To read it as PNG and save it as JPEG you need to decode it (as PNG) and then code it (as JPG).

> I would like to read an image and then change its format but without saving it.

The "format" of the image (in the PNG/JPEG sense) gives you a way of packing an image in a sequence of bits. So, your desire makes little sense. At most, you could store those bits in memory (what for?), but that would be the same as "saving it" (to memory instead of disk).

Comment: I actually want to send photo from my computer to a server, but it is in a non compressed format. That's why before I send it I want to transform the photo in a format that needs less space.
So Read->Change Format->Send

Comment: What means, in your context, "sending" an image? Writing it to a socket? If so, then write with `ImageIO.write`  to the socket stream, instead of writing to a file. There's no way of escaping the "decode (from JPEG or whatever) + encode (to PNG or whatever)" sequence.